# Align image on the same line

Tags: html, css

How can i align three image on the same line, so that when i resize the browser the image still are on the same line? Because now with my code i just tell them to float left so when the browser is resized some images go to a new line. I was looking something like to split the page into three columns.

```css
.containerh {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  float:left;
}

.overlayh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .overlayh {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

#imgh {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
}

.titleh {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: 0;
  top: 120px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: top .5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .titleh {
  top: 90px;
}

.buttonh {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left:0;
  top: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.buttonh a {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.containerh:hover .buttonh {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sx{float:left;margin-right:15px;}
```

```html
<div class="sx">
<div class="containerh">
  <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
  <p class="titleh">card title</p>
  <div class="overlayh"></div>
  <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="sx">
<div class="containerh">
  <img id="imgh"src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
  <p class="titleh">card title</p>
  <div class="overlayh"></div>
  <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
</div>
</div>
   
<div class="sx">
<div class="containerh">
  <img id="imgh"src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
  <p class="titleh">card title</p>
  <div class="overlayh"></div>
  <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` like this (i also updated some styling to fit the flex display) :

```css
/* This will create 3 columns with your images*/
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.containerh {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 50px 5px 0;
}
/* ---  */


.overlayh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .overlayh {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.titleh {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 30%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: bottom .5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .titleh {
  bottom: 40%;
}

.buttonh {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.buttonh a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.containerh:hover .buttonh {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="containerh">
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerh">
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="containerh">
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As flex is not supported in IE9 here is another solution using `inline-block` and `width` :

```css
/* This will create 3 columns with your images*/

.container {
  text-align: center;
  font-size:0; /*remove white spaces*/
}

.containerh {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px); /* take exactly 1/3 of the width minus margin*/
  margin: 50px 5px 0;
  font-size:initial; /* set the font back*/
}

/* ---  */

.overlayh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .overlayh {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.titleh {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 30%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: bottom .5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .titleh {
  bottom: 40%;
}

.buttonh {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.buttonh a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.containerh:hover .buttonh {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="containerh">
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerh">
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="containerh">
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it doesn't work unfortunatly. but i can provide you with another working  solution for IE ;)

Comment: @JoostS i added another supported solution

Comment: Sorry Temani, but combining pixels, inline-block and percentages will not work (properly) in IE9.

Comment: @JoostS unfortunately IE9 is limited and already forget what can be done on it :s i also cannot test it ... you may change inline-bock by floating but you said you don't want floating

Comment: @JoostS oh, i was pretty sure you are the OP but no :) ... why are you considering IE9 ? it's very old now and no more supported

Comment: Because unprefixed you are excluding more than 10% worldwide: https://caniuse.com/#search=Flex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158814/discussion-between-joosts-and-temani-afif).

Comment: Inline-block should not be used with a percentage when you use new lines in your code.

Comment: @JoostS what do you mean, i didn't get you ?

Comment: @JoostS simply because i didn't do a accurate calculation as it's a simple example to show that inline-block can be an alternative .. and i added because you said flex is not supported (i prefer to use flex) but i corrected the code to make the calculation accurate and we can use % with width without any issue with inline block element

Answer (score -1):

Please know that using unprefixed flexbox is not (properly) supported in 12% of the browsers worldwide (see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=Flex)).

I have made some small adjustments to Temani Afifs code to make it more cross-browser. First of all I removed flexbox to make it work in IE(9). I also borrowed the negative margin trick from Twitter Bootstrap to be able to combine percentages and pixels without `calc()`. Finally I prefixed `box-sizing`.

```css
/* This will create 3 columns with your images*/
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
.containerh {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 5px 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* ---  */
body > div {position: relative; margin: 0 15px;} 
.containerh > div {position: relative;}

.overlayh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .overlayh {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%; display: block;
}

.titleh {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 30%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: bottom .5s ease;
}

.containerh:hover .titleh {
  bottom: 40%;
}

.buttonh {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.buttonh a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  z-index: 1;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.containerh:hover .buttonh {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div><div class="container">
  <div class="containerh"><div>
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="containerh"><div>
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div></div>

  <div class="containerh"><div>
    <img id="imgh" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488628075628-e876f502d67a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=" alt="" />
    <p class="titleh">card title</p>
    <div class="overlayh"></div>
    <div class="buttonh"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Looks like you are downvoting this solution because it contains an inconvenient truth. The person who answered the accepted answer is unable to make his alternative code work in IE9. This shows the problem with most people writing CSS. There is a simple solution that works for all browsers, but most people are already married to their next generation code. They create expensive code and big cross browser problems for their clients. I think that is irresponsible behaviour.